# CSS: Compound a path to see the content below

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I have a box that has a border with a gradient on it, basically, it is a gradient box with a dark background box on it. Then I have another gradient box on it and I need to cut out some part of it to see the content below it - make it transparent. What would be the best approach to get this done right? Please see the screenshot to better understand what is needed.

[image]

Comment: Is SVG out of the picture? It's easy to accomplish there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you can set the border of your inner component. Thanks to not touching the background properties, it is perfectly transparent.

```css
.inner {
    border: 10px solid;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(
       45deg,
       rgb(0, 143, 104),
       rgb(250, 224, 66)
    );
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

Comment: Does this approach support border-radius? Does it have good browser support?

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not working with border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

For the *position* of the elements, I would do it with grid or with position absolute (up to you).

Regarding the *background and borders*: set the background of the bigger element, leaving the other element without background. Same border for both elements.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 225px;
  height: 150px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.big,
.small {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row:1;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(red, orange) 1;
}

.big {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, gray);
}

.small {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: end;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
 <div>
```

Keep in mind that you might want to choose a raster image or an SVG for these graphic elements.